# Dispatch Group Serial Queue

Tags: ios, queue, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to understand what will be the correct way to create Serial Dispatch Group for background threaded tasks. Example:

I have a video which I want to split into 5 parts. So in theory this will be the queue cycle:

- Run `AVAssetExportSession` on a background thread
- Wait for it to finish
- Notify finished
- Run `AVAssetExportSession` on a background thread
- And so on and on

I've been digging through tutorials regarding this issue, yet I couldn't find an appropriate way to achieve this.

Any help would be highly appricated!

Best Regards, Roi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "serial dispatch group". Serial/concurrent is a property of a queue, not of a group.

Given that `AVAssetExportSession` is, itself, an asynchronous process, simple attempts to add it to a serial queue will not work. Two approaches seem logical. You can either:

1. You can wrap the `exportAsynchronously(completionHandler:)` in an asynchronous custom `Operation` subclass. You can then add these five operations to a serial Operation queue. You can give them individual completion blocks if you want. And/or you can then make a completion operation dependent on those five operations.

   or
2. You can write a recursive function that performs request `i`, and in its completion handler, you can have it call itself for `i + 1`. And it just needs to check to see if `i < 5` (or whatever).

Comment: Hey Rob! Thank you for replying. I've used the recursion option. Works as expected, as well with just a few lines of code. Thank you Rob! :)

Comment: Just saw I forgot to accept the answer. Sorry for the delay Rob!

Answer (score 4):

Synchronization via groups is useful if the tasks are to be processed in parallel and serially and the last task is unclear. But your problem is completely serial.

Why don't you use just a *serial queue* for your purpose? You can add the five blocks to that queue and they will be executed in the desired order. You might also solve your problem with just a single block running in background.

Comment: Hey Clemens, thank you for replying! I've used Rob recursive solution (easier to implement, as least for me). Tho nice approach. Thanks!